# how can i make a JtextField like DateField in which to Slash(/) is permanentately added

Tags: java, swing

How can I make a `JtextField` like `DateField` which contains perminantly visible slashes dividing Month, Day, and Year values. Like in the example below, the slashes are visible when the field is empty, and when the user types in a value, the date value will go around the slashes. That is, if the user types `031618` in the field, it will appear as `03/16/18`:

[image: the textField will look like this in which "/" are not erasable]

I have seen examples of this on the inernet, so I know it is possible, but I don't know how to make it work myself.

Comment: are you talking about Swing or another UI framework/technology? why would you want to use a JTextField for a Date anyway? It's much better (and probably easier) to just import a DatePicker

Comment: Use a JFormattedTextField. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use FormattedTextFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: in Billing and accounting software everything should be done using keyboard because in these type of software the speed of Operation should be fast .so i am avoid that things for which we have to use mouse.that's why i want to do this by this way@Stultuske

Comment: but if i am using JFormatted Field than i can erase the "/" using backspace and delete .i want that the software user can not be erase this by backspace and delete.@camickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use the [MaskFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html):

  - as @camickr has already said, also check out [Using MaskFormatter - How to Use Formatted Text Fields (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public final class MaskFormatterTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    String mask = "##/##/##";
    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter(mask));
    field.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    field.setText("031618");

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 10, 10));
    p.add(field);
    p.add(new JTextField("03/16/18"));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return panel;
  }
  protected static MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
      formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
      System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return formatter;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new MaskFormatterTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JFormattedTextField` rather then `JTextField`, and use the class `SimpleDateFormat`, like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(dateFormat);
```

Comment: Is there no way around using the outdated and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class? That’s bad…